# What's the equivalent of project Module in salesforce

Tags: case, solutions

As you know , A project module is the main module in PM tools such as : Redmine, MS TFS ,...

However, when i search on this module on salesForce, i don't find anything, even i find how to create task . But  , i cannot link this task to project. Instead of project i note other modules can include tasks
[image]

## My question  is exactly:

#### Where can i find project module ?

#### IF cannot , what is the equivalent of project in CRM project  : Solution?! Case ?! .... .Knowing the available modules are the following :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for some type of project management functionality out of the box from Salesforce, which unfortunately there isn't. I would take a look at some of the options that are available in the AppExchange, as even the free ones offer great basic functionality for project management within Salesforce.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?filter=a0L3000000OvSOlEAN,1